# Counterexample t0 prove that B is not a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow E$ and let $A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$. Let

$B = \{y \in E: \exists x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y  \}$.

We have to prove that $B$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Is the following example a counterexample?

Let $\Omega= \{ \{ 1,2 \},\{1,3\},\{1,3\}\}$,

Define f:

$f(\{ 1,2 \})=\{ 1,2 \} \in B$

$f(\{ 2,3 \})=\{ 2,3 \} \in B$

$f(\{ 1,3 \})=\{ 1,3 \} \in B$

Now

$\{ 2,3 \} \cap \{ 1,3 \} = \{3\} \notin B $ and hence $B$ is not an algebra which implies that it is not a $\sigma$-algebra. I'm not sure whether this counterexample is OK since $f$ is not defined on all elements of $A$?

Comment: It seems $f$ should be defined on $A$, not on $\Omega$. Later on, are you sure you want to define $\Omega$ as a three-elements set of pairs?

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the problem that $f$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $E$. I'm not sure, but that's what I came up with during the exam.

Comment: The [$\exists x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$] is absurd.

Comment: @user114860 If the problem is really stated like that, someone must have made a typo.

Comment: Yeah, that is the most probable explanation.